# Node-RED module in Azure Edge running on Raspberry Pi 4 prompting "backoff" error

Tags: node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to get the [noderededgemodule](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule) to run on the Azure Edge on a Raspberry Pi 4. I have a few other modules running fine, but this one prompts the "backoff" error. I'm not sure what this means, and how to resolve it. I'm currently using the AMD64 module but have tried ARM32

```css
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iotedge check

Configuration checks
--------------------
√ config.yaml is well-formed - OK
√ config.yaml has well-formed connection string - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
√ config.yaml has correct hostname - OK
√ config.yaml has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - OK
√ latest security daemon - OK
√ host time is close to real time - OK
× container time is close to host time - Error
    Detected time drift between host and container
‼ DNS server - Warning
    Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: certificates - Warning
    The Edge device is using self-signed automatically-generated development certificates.
    They will expire in 77 days (at 2020-07-27 15:36:55 UTC) causing module-to-module and downstream device communication to fail on an active deployment.
    After the certs have expired, restarting the IoT Edge daemon will trigger it to generate new development certs.
    Please consider using production certificates instead. See https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-certs for best practices.
√ production readiness: container engine - OK
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.

Connectivity checks
-------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub MQTT port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - OK

17 check(s) succeeded.
5 check(s) raised warnings. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
1 check(s) raised errors. Re-run with --verbose for more details.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iotedge logs nodered
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exec format error` is because you are trying to run a x86_64 (AMD64) compiled binary on the ARM processor in the Raspberry Pi.

That just won't work, you can only run ARM binaries on an ARM CPU.

Comment: That makes sense. I've changed module to run on ARM32 which changes the error

Comment: Then ask a new question with the right details and logs